# How to get PFound metric score with YetiRank loss in CatBoost Ranker for Optuna?

Tags: catboost

I train CatBoost Ranker in Optuna with YetiRank and want to optimize Pfound. If I write params such way (as on 1 screen) and then I want to pull out the metric after fitting -  I try to use ranker.best_score_['validation']['PFound']. But when I run, I get a KeyError: 'validation' - and the best_score_ dictionary itself is empty.
Surprisingly, if i change the custom metric in params to Pairlogit instead of PFound (on the last screen) , the best_score_ dictionary already contains two metrics for validation - including the PFound which I need - and I take it from there and optimize it in optuna.
What did I write wrong? Hot to get PFound to optimize it with YetiRank loss for Optuna correctly?[screen_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BUvQ.jpg)
[screen_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44vf3.jpg)
[screen_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHlXY.jpg)

Also I tried writing params without custom_metric option, and tried to directly write best_score_['Validation']['YetiRank'] - but keyError: 'Validation' was the same.
That option is OK for PairLogit loss, for example